# How to use the regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which has a line of the form:

> Thu Apr 28 20:51:37 +0000 2011 :: Melanie Caldwell :: judeyqwaller ::
> Hong Kong :: P000352670 - Toshiba Satellite 5205 Series TouchPad:
> Toshiba Satellite 5205 Series TouchPad - P000352670COMPATIB...
> http:// t.co/QU5jA6U5

I need to pull out only the part of the line which starts after `:: Hong Kong::` i.e.
`P000352670...`, and so on.

How can I do this using a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regular expression for this it is fairly simple, you could do something like:

```
x = string.split("::")[-1]
```

if the string is your text line

Edit for your new question (assuming you are using python 2.5+):

```
string = "682698_62876_26861"
print string.rpartition('_')[0]
```

This will output exactly what you need:

```
682698_62876
```

Comment: I have a back up question to this. Suppose I have a variable which  has the value 682698_62876_26861 in it. How do I split this to get an output of only 682698_62876?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
res = ' :: '.join(row.split(' :: ')[4:])
```

Comment: I tried this just now. And if print res, it doesn't print anything. Just a white space

Comment: A joke about using regular expression: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."

Comment: @user1452759. try printing `res`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> row = "Thu Apr 28 20:51:37 +0000 2011 :: Melanie Caldwell :: judeyqwaller :: Hong Kong :: P000352670 - Toshiba Satellite 5205 Series TouchPad: Toshiba Satellite 5205 Series TouchPad - P000352670COMPATIB... http://t.co/QU5jA6U5"
>>> row.rpartition('::')[2]
' P000352670 - Toshiba Satellite 5205 Series TouchPad: Toshiba Satellite 5205 Series TouchPad - P000352670COMPATIB... http://t.co/QU5jA6U5'
```